# Как получить значения ip адресов в массив - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, регулярные-выражения, ip, webrtc

Добрый день! Есть код. который получает через webrtc ip адреса юзера и выводит значения в консоль.
Можно как то получить значения ip адресов в массив ?
Пробовал вместо getIPs(function(ip){console.log(ip);}); функции подставить var arr=[]; getIPs(function(ip){arr.push(ip);});
Но почему то при выводе значений массива получаю udentified.

```js
//get the IP addresses associated with an account
function getIPs(callback){
    var ip_dups = {};
 
    //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
        || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
        || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var mediaConstraints = {
        optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
    };
 
    //firefox already has a default stun server in about:config
    //    media.peerconnection.default_iceservers =
    //    [{"url": "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]
    var servers = undefined;
 
    //add same stun server for chrome
    if(window.webkitRTCPeerConnection)
        servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};
 
    //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);
 
    //listen for candidate events
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){
 
        //skip non-candidate events
        if(ice.candidate){
 
            //match just the IP address
            var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3})/
            var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];
 
            //remove duplicates
            if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                callback(ip_addr);
 
            ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
        }
    };
 
    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createDataChannel("");
 
    //create an offer sdp
    pc.createOffer(function(result){
 
        //trigger the stun server request
        pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});
 
    }, function(){});
}
 
//Test: Print the IP addresses into the console
getIPs(function(ip){console.log(ip);});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот такой код.

```js
//get the IP addresses associated with an account
function getIPs(callback) {
  getIPs.ip_dups = {};

  //compatibility for firefox and chrome
  var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection ||
    window.mozRTCPeerConnection ||
    window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
  var mediaConstraints = {
    optional: [{
      RtpDataChannels: true
    }]
  };

  //firefox already has a default stun server in about:config
  //    media.peerconnection.default_iceservers =
  //    [{"url": "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]
  var servers = undefined;

  //add same stun server for chrome
  if (window.webkitRTCPeerConnection)
    servers = {
      iceServers: [{
        urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"
      }]
    };

  //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
  var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

  //listen for candidate events
  pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {

    //skip non-candidate events
    if (ice.candidate) {

      //match just the IP address
      var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3})/
      var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];

      //remove duplicates
      if (getIPs.ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined) {
        getIPs.ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
        callback(ip_addr);
      }


    }
  };

  //create a bogus data channel
  pc.createDataChannel("");

  //create an offer sdp
  pc.createOffer(function(result) {

    //trigger the stun server request
    pc.setLocalDescription(result, function() {}, function() {});

  }, function() {});
}

//Test: Print the IP addresses into the console
getIPs(function(ip) {
  console.log(getIPs.ip_dups);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось

Answer (score -1):

Соберите данные колбеком в массив, вместо вывода на консоль.

```js
var ips = []
getIPs(function(ip) { ips.push(ip); });
console.log(ips)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось

Comment: В момент выполнения `console.log(ips)` массив `ips` может быть пустым.

Comment: да как раз в этом и была проблема, он пустой если так написать, так как функция callback отрабатывает позже.

Comment: Я пытался конкретное значение массива вывести и получал - undefiend. Но при выводе именно массива в консоль в хроме, браузер намекнул что массив заполняется позже.